# only one number is getting fetched?

Tags: codeigniter

```
    $details    = $this->crud_model->get_contact_details();
    foreach ($details as $row2) {
    }
```

from this i can able to access `$row2['phone']` getting only last phone number from the record every time,but i need the number of the person whom i want to search for..

```
<td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$row2['phone']."</td>
```

from this is i access `$row2['phone']` getting only last phone number from the record every time,but i need the number of the person whom i want to search for..

```
<td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$row2['phone']."</td>
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help you with just a variable name and an empty for loop. Please update your question with more details. Also read your question again - the same line is repeating 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
foreach($details as $row2){
    echo"<td style='border:1px solid black;padding:10px;'>".$row2['phone']."</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your `get_contact_details()` function which return  result as an array of objects then using foreach to get all result value

```
foreach($details as $row2){
    echo"<td style='border:1px solid    black;padding:10px;'>".$row2['phone']." </td>";
   }
```